# How to get SQL Server DateTime2 field in ODBC native client

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, client

I am having a table as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [tagname] [nvarchar(30)] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime2] NOT NULL
)
```

I am using below code on client side in c++ to get the tag date

```
TIMESTAMP_STRUCT ts;
SQLLEN cbhiredate;
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLGetData(hStmt, 2, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP, &ts, sizeof(TIMESTAMP_STRUCT), &cbhiredate)))
```

It is working fine in most of the cases but in some case the date milliseconds value is getting rounded. For example, if date value is 2020/01/11 17:15:38.6850000 in SQL table then while fetching using above query the date value is getting changed to 2020/01/11 17:15:38.686 in client side code.

Is there anything wrong I am doing while fetching the data from SQL server. This is happening with SQL Server 2012 SP4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your datetime2 data type has a precision of 100ns - and you are putting that value into a type with a precision of milliseconds.

If the actual date/time value is 2020/01/11 17:15:38.685900 rounding must round it up to the .686.  If the actual value was .685400 it would round down to .685

If you change the data type to datetime2(3) - it would be stored in SQL Server with a precision of milliseconds and you wouldn't get any rounding of the values.

Comment: The exact value in SQL server is 2020/01/11 17:15:38.6850000, so while fetching from out client side, it should not get rounded. But still it is happening.  So it could be something wrong either with SQL server or in the Client side code.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure the value in SQL Server .6850000 then there must be something else causing the rounding.  I would still change the data type in SQL Server to datetime2(3) - this will be accurate to the millisecond and avoid any rounding issues.